# MySQL - SQL search by two condidtion

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I'd like to ask how or if is it possible to select from this:

```
Street 1
Street 2, City
Street 3, Country  //many different words are possible after comma.
Street 4
```

I need only:

```
Street 1
Street 2
Street 3
Street 4
```

As you can see, one delimiter is comma but second delimiter is, let's say that there is nothing.

I can select streets where is comma but I can't find a solution for street without comma.

```
SELECT LEFT(physicalDeliveryOfficeName,LOCATE(',',physicalDeliveryOfficeName) - 1) AS physicalDeliveryOfficeName 
FROM contacts 
GROUP BY LEFT(physicalDeliveryOfficeName,LOCATE(',',physicalDeliveryOfficeName) - 1)
```

Can you help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please tag the question accordingly. Please post sample data and expected results. Group by doesn't make sense without an aggregate function - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I use MySQL sorry, I forgot to mention it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(physicalDeliveryOfficeName, ',', 1) AS physicalDeliveryOfficeName 
FROM contacts
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change "As physicalDeliveryOfficeName " to "AS PDOname", and you can group by PDOname - less calculations.
2. Easiest way - add comma to all strings, so you will definently have comma:

```
SELECT LEFT(CONCAT(physicalDeliveryOfficeName,','),LOCATE(',',CONCAT(physicalDeliveryOfficeName,',')) - 1) AS PDOname
FROM contacts GROUP BY PDOname
```

Comment: *Change "As physicalDeliveryOfficeName " to "AS PDOname", and you can group by PDOname* - not needed. `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` means output column whereas `contacts.physicalDeliveryOfficeName` must be used for source table data accessing - output column name masks source column name.

Comment: You will calculate the LEFT function twice if you use physicalDeliveryOfficeName.

Comment: Why have told this to you? MySQL easily reuses calculated expression value if its full text is equal fully. You may test - if you're right then execution times of these variants must have detectable difference.

Comment: Yeah. You right. 
And I checked the query from your answer, it's even faster.